# Performance issue while creating runtime html table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application where I need to create a runtime html table in a page. The function fetch the data from the database and create the runtime the html table and render on the page. That table contain 6-8 columns and 150-200 rows and each row have some input testboxes. Everything is working fine but there is a performance issue while rendering the html table in the aspx page. Below is the code.

```
  private string GenereateTableData(int rowCount, MyDataList obDataList)
    {
        var table = new StringBuilder();
        string image = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            table.AppendFormat("<tr id='trModelDetail" + rowCount + "' name='RECORDNUM" + rowCount + "' >");

            table.AppendFormat("<td class='aa' align='left' width='80px' style='background-color: #fcfae6;' >");
            table.AppendFormat("<input type='text' name='' id='" + rowCount.ToString() + "' readonly='1' style='width: 75px;background-color: #fcfae6;' class='ActionTBox' maxlength='4' onblur='hideMsgDiv();' value='" + rowCount + "'/>");
            table.AppendFormat("</td>");

            table.AppendFormat("<td class='stdformfont' align='left' width='80px'>");
            table.AppendFormat("<input type='text' name='aa' id='aa' style='width: 75px;' class='' maxlength='10' />");
            table.AppendFormat("<input type='text' name='aa' id='aa' style='width: 75px;display:none; class='ActionTeox' maxlength='10' />");
            table.AppendFormat("</td>");


            table.AppendFormat("</tr>");

            return table.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            table = null;
        }
    }


    private void ShowData(MyDataList obDataList)
    {
        var table = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {

            table.AppendFormat("<table id='modelDetailsTable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>");


            for (int iCount = 0; iCount < obDataList.Count; iCount++)
            {
                // Fill the table with data 
                table.AppendFormat(GenereateTableData(iCount, obDataList[iCount]));

            }

            table.AppendFormat("</table>");

            // Show table in UI
            divData.InnerHtml = table.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            table = null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your coding part. Problem is the created webpage is too heavy for browser. I would suggest to use tabs (which would need javascript or something) and reduce the number of rows shown in single time.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to create the HTML table structure on client side and just pass the data. This will reduce huge number of repeated data transmission from server to client.  You can use [ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) to call JQuery function along with the data and process it on client side.

Hope this helps.